# Angular 2 form valid by default

Tags: validation, angular, angular2-forms

Having issue with form validation .

i want to submit the form only when form is valid.

but with the empty inputs and clicking on submit button is submitting the form although the inputs are empty.

```
<form name="equipmentForm" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && addEquipment()" validate>
```

Inputs be like this.

```
 <input name="equimentId" class="text-input form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.equipmentNumber" pattern="^[0-9][0-9]{1,19}$" title="Equipment ID. can be upto 20 digits only.">
```

I cant post the whole code although.

this

> **f.form.valid** is true from form initialization

wanted to acheive something like this

```
<div *ngIf="!model.equipmentModel && f.submitted" class="text-danger">
                        Please enter Equipment Model
</div>
```

So on submit i want to show this message instead of default browser's.
but this **f.form.valid** is goddamn true from default.

Comment: you have to add `required` to the form inputs if you want them to be invalid when empty

Comment: Thats not the issue here, i have similar form but without required attribute and in that "f.form.valid"  isnt true

Comment: well that's because maybe you have other rules applied like pattern, but generally a input is valid if it's empty and not having the `required`, so that's definitely the reason why your form is being submitted.

Comment: But thats not happening in other form i have.
although there isnt much difference in those,ill post a plunkr in some time.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `required` attribute to your `input` tags to, then as @Cobus Kruger mentioned, form will not be submitted untill it is filled.

However you can also give a try to `pristine`, `dirty` options, which allow you to check if the user did any changes to the form so in this case your condition may look like this:

```
 <form name="equipmentForm" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && f.form.dirty ? addEquipment() : ''" validate>
```

and the input:

```
 <input name="equimentId" class="text-input form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.equipmentNumber" pattern="^[0-9][0-9]{1,19}$" title="Equipment ID. can be upto 20 digits only." required />
```

In this case it will check if any changes were applied to the input, and submit the form if both conditions are met.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the `required` attribute on the input, then the form will not be submitted unless a value is filled in. But that only covers values that were not supplied and you may want to check for invalid values as well.

The usual way is to disable the submit button unless the form is valid. Like this:

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!f.form.valid">Submit</button>
```

The [Angular documentation about form validation](http://web.archive.org/web/20161111065216/https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#template1) also shows this. Look near the bottom of the "Simple template driven forms" section

Comment: i dont wanna disable the submit button . Although in your case also the f.form.valid is true .
So it wont disalbe the button

Comment: Well, in that case you'll need to check the validation behind the submit button. In most cases, people don't like disabling the submit button because it gives no visual feedback. The same Angular doc I linked also shows a way around that.

Comment: but f.form.valid is true :(

Comment: See, this is where you need to post more code. The code you gave looks like a normal template-based form, but checking `form.valid` looks more like a reactive form. Please show at least a trimmed declaration for `f.form`.

Comment: you got 3 people here telling you that you need the `required` attribute, I don't know what more you expect. @manishkumar

Comment: ya ill post a plunkr , dude(right now at work) so post work ill put plunkr code

Answer (score 0):

In function which you call on submit you can pass form as parameter and then check. In html you will need to pass form instance:

```
<form name="equipmentForm" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addEquipment(f)" validate>
```

In typescript:

```
addEquipment(form){
   if(form.invalid){
       return;
   }

   //If it is valid it will continue to here...
}
```